# Drupal 7 adding rel to the href's of Login and Registration

Tags: 7, users, javascript

I'm using Lightbox as a modal box solution and have been having 
an issue trying to get modal windows for the default Login and
Registration links. I'm trying to access from inside a module that
I"m currently using to make all the changes. I've tried several 
other "Box" solutions and Lightbox seems to be what I'm looking for, 
but I cannot figure out the hook to add rel='lightbox' to login and 
reg. Could someone point out what it is for me?

**EDIT** I tried using this in my base theme, which will give me a
modal on both reg and login, but shows an empty form?

function spti_base_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

```
/* .....stuff..... */

    // add the system user-menu into the page as its own thing
    $variables['platform_user_menu'] = menu_navigation_links('menu-platform-user-menu');

    foreach($variables['platform_user_menu'] as &$hijackLinks) { $hijackLinks['attributes']['rel'] = 'lightframe'; }

    $variables['page']['platform_user_menu'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'links__system_user_menu',
      '#links' =>   $variables['platform_user_menu'],
      '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'platform-user-menu',
        'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
      ),
  );

/* .....stuff..... */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could spend time tearing apart templates, and hacking in the required code, I would say the cleaner, 'more drupal' solution would be to use a combination of

- Menu and menu items
- The module [menu attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes)

From the project page:

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes
>   for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.